Install error for Ubuntu Studio on Gateway DX4840
I downloaded the torrent version of ubuntustudio-24.04-dvd-amd64.iso, checked the SHA256 (it matched), and used both Rufus and UNetbootin to make a bootable with a Lexar USB3.1 64GB stick. I'm able to boot into it and use all the features and programs, no problem, but after getting to the Time Zone screen of the install pages I get the attached error message.
[][1
I'm trying to install it side by side with Windows 10. It's a Crucial 1TB, split between my C: (300GB) and my Data (611GB) I tried to give Ubuntu Studio 100GB of the C: partition.
I've now tried this latest, and also version 18.04 (2.8GB) to burn to a rewriteable DVD to try that route. It wouldn't even boot into live mode. Then I tried Kubuntu on a USB stick, figuring if it was small it might install easier, then I could upgrade. That didn't work either. It booted into live mode, then got the same error message.
Here is the log from that error message:
Jul 05 12:02:26 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Jul 05 12:02:28 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:02:29 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Jul 05 12:03:22 ubuntu-studio subiquity_event.5706[5706]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:

Gateway DX4840
Intel Core i5 3.2 GHz
16GB memory
